# Trouble with outputting a mean for each element in a cell array (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I have a 1x28 cell array called magV with each element containing a 246x247 matrix containing mostly NaNs.

I am trying to set up a for loop to go through each of these matrices and calculate a mean. The attempt so far:

```
mean_speeds = cell(1,28);

for x = 1 : 28
    mean_speeds{x} = mean(magV{x});
end
```

This doesn't work; it just outputs another 1x28 cell array, with each element containing a 1x28 row of NaNs

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you want to deal with NaNs? az zeros?

Comment: If you want to calculate the mean of the entire matrix, consider using `mean` twice so that you find the mean of the output row vector, but the answer below is solid.  It will remove `NaN` entries from each matrix and form a single vector, then the mean of this vector will be computed.  That should work!

Answer (score 2):

Mean of anything containing NaN is a NaN. Remove . . .

```
mean(magV{x(~isnan(x))});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `mean` function does not support NaN arguments. You can add a logic step to remove the invalid numbers then calculate the mean of the resulting array.

Or, you can use `nanmean`: [see the nanmean Help Page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nanmean.html)

Comment: Minor note: `nanmean` is part of the Statistics Toolbox.  A more portable answer is learnvst's.

Comment: Fair point. Didn't even notice that. I miss this from time to time as we use this in a research lab. Our licenses have all the toolboxes...

Comment: Ah yes.  One can forget about that too when you have a full academic license :D.  I have upvoted in any case as it is technically correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cellfun` to get rid of the loops.

If you want to ignore nan's

```
noNaN = cellfun(@(x) mean(x(~isnan(x))), magV, 'uni', 0);
```

If you want to treat them as zeros

```
zeroNaN = cellfun(@(x) sum(x(~isnan(x)))/numel(x), magV, 'uni', 0);
```

Comment: And actually if you want a vector rather than a cell array the `'uni',0` is unnecessary.